# Servlet/JSP web application design

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

A few days ago I installed tomcat 7 and decided to try building a small web site. Nothing much, just some UI and some little logic behind.

I know what servlets and JSPs are, and how they work. So I wrote a JSP, which sends the homepage. Then I started to set up some links, and... the first problem arose. What if I have some content in the page that should be present in *every* page, for example a navigation bar. More generally, what I need maybe is a static skeleton to be filled dynamically.

I googled a lot and dived in the labyrinthine jungle of web programming.

It really is a jungle. Couldn't understand much. I just wanted to build a web site from Servlets and JSP and *bam*, I found myself installing Eclipse Indigo, Ant, Apache Velocity, SpringMVC and a bunch of other stuff. It is frustrating, every tutorial propose a different toolchain.

I just wanted to fill the content dynamically. Something slightly more flexible than JSP, maybe. This is the question. What are the most common techniques/conventions?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jsp stuff, you can include other jsp stuff !

http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/1.2/syntaxref1214.html

Why not doing a

> fixed_things.jsp

and then include it in every other jsp ?